# Actionscript 3: Monitoring the activity level for multiple Microphones doesn't seem to work

Tags: actionscript-3

For a project I want to show all available webcams and microphones, so that the user can easily select whichever webcam/microphone combination they prefer. I run into an issue with the microphones listing though.

Each microphone is listed with an activity animation and it's name. I am able to list all Microphones just fine (using the Microphone.names Array), but it seems like I can only get the activity viewer to work for one microphone. The other microphones show up with '-1' activity, which (as far as I know) is Flex for 'present, but not in use'. When unplugging the microphone that *does* show activity, the next one (in my case, the mic-in line on my motherboard) shows up with '0' activity (it's not connected, so that makes sense).

During my testing I have a total of 3 microphones available, the not-connected onboard mic-in port, and two connected microphones.

For testing purposes I use a timer that traces the current microphone activity each 100ms and the graph is also shown.

It does not seem to matter what default microphone I set via flash' settings panel.

**The code**

I've only attached the revelant code snippets below to make it easier for you to read through them. Please let me know if you prefer the entire code.

**Main application.mxml**

*Note: cont is a VBox. i is defined before this code snippet.*

```
var mics:Array = Microphone.names;
for(i=0; i < mics.length; i++){
   var mic:settingsMicEntry = new assets.settingsMicEntry;
   mic.d = {name: mics[i], index: i};

   cont.addChild(mic);
}
```

**assets/settingsMicEntry.mxml**

*timer is defined before this code snippet. the SoundTransform is added to silence local microphone playback. Excluding this code does not solve the problem, sadly (I've tried). display is an MXML Canvas object.*

```
mic = Microphone.getMicrophone(d.index);
if(mic){
    // Temporary: The Microphones' visualizer
   var bar:Box = new Box();
   bar.y = 50;
   bar.height = 0;
   bar.width = 66;
   bar.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0x003300);
   display.addChild(bar);

   var tf:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
   mic.setLoopBack(true);
   mic.soundTransform = tf;

   timer = new Timer(100);
   timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void{
      var h:int = Math.floor((display.height/100)*mic.activityLevel);

      bar.height = (h>-1) ? h : 0;
      bar.y = (h>-1) ? display.height-h : display.height;

      trace('TIMER: '+h+' from '+d.name);
   });
   timer.start();
}
```

I'm pulling my hear out here, so any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

-Dave

*Ps.: Pardon the messiness of the code!*

Comment: In case it helps; I just now started from scratch, removing all loops and use of external MXML files but as soon as I add a second microphone, the first one keeps reporting -1 for activity.

Strangely enough I had no problem accessing multiple webcams using an almost identical setup.

Comment: Update: It seems that only one microphone is allowed to be played back locally (using setLoopBack). When all microphones are connected to a NetStream connection, it's possible to see the activity of each microphone. Does anyone know of a way around this? Setting up a netstream connection with all microphones enabled is certainly not a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a mock NetStream connection using the [OSMF](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/osmf/Downloads) library.

You'll need to import the classes from the NetMocker project (under libs/adobe - org.osmf.netmocker) and the classes NetConnectionCodes and NetStreamCodes (under framework/OSMF - org.osmf.net).

Answer (score 0):

Check out that you need to create one NetStream for each microphone