# Detect activity level of microphone in flex

Tags: apache-flex, microphone

I have to detect avtivityLevel of microphone in Flex. I am using the activityLevel property of Microphone class but as I found out it always return -1 even if I have done Microphone.getMicrophone().
To detect activity level we have to set microphone.setLoopback = true;

Does anybody know how to do this without using loop back as I do not want to hear my sound back just monitor the activity level

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microphone won't show any activity until it is attached to a NetStream connection. You can use a MockNetStream to fake the connection using OSMF - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253105/actionscript-3-monitoring-the-activity-level-for-multiple-microphones-doesnt-se/2581786#2581786).

Comment: Yes, I did it by using a mock net stream.